# Failing to set up TensorFlow on Mac

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pycharm

I am trying to set up a ML environment on my new Mac device which has a M1 chip. I followed this [guide](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/) to get TensorFlow installed. However I do not know how to set up the environment on Pycharm. When I try to install Tensorflow as a package it outputs the following:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-macos (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-macos

I have tried using different Python versions but it the same output keeps popping.

Could you help me with setting up the environment on Pycharm? More specifically what environment and interpreter should I select?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to include all information in your question, including error messages, etc. Just saying "it fails" is super vague and people will not be able to help you in that case.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I always follow this repository (Thanks to Daniel Bourke). Follow this steps which are provided in the repository and I hope this will get the job done. Enjoy <3

https://github.com/mrdbourke/m1-machine-learning-test

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
brew install hdf5
export HDF5_DIR=/opt/homebrew/opt/hdf5
pip install --no-binary=h5py h5py
pip install tensorflow-macos
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/apple-silicon-transition) on my Macbook Pro M1 and set up a separate environment for each problem.  Works fine.